# Why Shift+Tab combination changes value of control?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I'm going to tell you about very very strange behavior.

Just imagine the form with vertically oriented `StackPanel`, which some controls, which have some values:

```
    <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="StartDate"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <dxe:DateEdit FontSize="14"
                     TabIndex="1"
                     Margin="0 2.5 0 2.5" 
                     MinWidth="126"                                             
                     EditValue="{Binding StartDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                     ShowClearButton="False" ToolTip="Planned date"/>
        <RadioButton IsTabStop="False"/>
        <Button Content="Button" IsTabStop="False"/>
    </StackPanel>
    
    <TextBlock Text="EndDate"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <dxe:DateEdit FontSize="14"
                      TabIndex="2"
                      Margin="0 2.5 0 2.5" 
                      MinWidth="126"                                             
                      EditValue="{Binding EndDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                      ShowClearButton="False" ToolTip="Planned date"/>
        <RadioButton IsTabStop="False"/>
        <Button Content="Button" IsTabStop="False"/>
    </StackPanel>
    
    <dxe:TextEdit TabIndex="3"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I want to take note, that the problem is with "EndDate" `DateEdit`.

Each of controls in container has own TabIndex value. If I use `Tab`, focus jumps from one to another as it's expected.
So, now about unexpected strange behavior:
When the focus is on `TextEdit`, and I press `Shift+Tab`, the `EndDateEdit` is focused, but it's value changes on `NULL`.
I've tried to debug it, so what I can tell you now:

There are no any global styles, which could have influence on this.
The value is not changed when `GotFocus` event starts.
`EndDateEdit` value is binded to property in VM, but program cannot reach the point in it's `set` method, when the value is changed, but it's really changed(it can be seen while handling `LostFocus` and `EditValueChanged` events).

I've asked DevExpress support such a question, but they couldn't repeat such scenario. And I think, you won't be able, too.

I'm sorry for such question, it seems like magic, or my bad somewhere. But I really don't know if what could cause such behavior. May be anyone has had such problem?

Comment: Have you checked the Output for binding expression path errors. It seems that at the moment the binding is evaluated, it has an invalid source/path?

Comment: @zaphod-ii, binding works well, when I change the date value manually or using DateEdit's calendar Popup, program enters the Set method point. I can note, that StartDateEdit is the same, but after Shift+Tab on it there is no such problem.

Comment: As result, I've handled EditValueChanged event for assigning last value is current has become NULL. But visually it still disappears.